# cannot connect as a user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with SQL Server2012, my instance name is NETA\SQLEXPRESS.

So I addded new user to Security, added a new database that I want to manage, restarted server, and then I want to login as this user. I choose SQL Authentication, type in login and password and I get:

```
Cannot conect to NETA\SQLEXPRESS
Login Failed for user 'peter' (Microsoft SQL Server Error: 18456)
```

Does anyone know why this happen ?

Comment: did you enable SQL authentication?  Right-click your server and choose 'properties.'  Look at the 'Securities' section and see if 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode' is selected.

Comment: This might help as well, error message is deliberately obscure. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx